# Angular failing to get the localstorage value in the ngOnInit

Tags: angular, rxjs, local-storage

i got a weird error using angular v17, im still a newbie with it

**First of all im gonna start with my service ,**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../../model/user';
import { BehaviorSubject, startWith, tap } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
  private url = "http://Localhost:8080/"
  private currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<string>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user') || 'null'));
  currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user') || 'null');
    if (user) {
      this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
    }
  }

  signup(user: User) {
    return this.http.post<User>(`${this.url}Signup`, user).pipe(
      tap((response: User) => {
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.firstName));
        this.currentUserSubject.next(response.firstName);
      })
    )
  }

  login(user: User) {
    return this.http.post<User>(`${this.url}Login`, user).pipe(
      tap((response: User) => {
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.firstName));
        this.currentUserSubject.next(response.firstName);
      })
    )
  }

  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('user');
    this.currentUserSubject.next('');
  }
}
```

the backend works fine and everything is working fine i add the user to the backend and i set the username to the local torage,

[image]

the problem now is I want to get the name from the local storage and display it in the header, which I call in the app.component.html

```
 <app-header></app-header>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**this is my header.component.ts**

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, OnChanges, OnInit, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { NavigationEnd, Router, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService } from '../service/user/User.service';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Observable, filter, switchMap } from 'rxjs';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterModule, CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrl: './header.component.css'
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  user: string = '';

  constructor(private userService: UserService,) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userService.currentUser.subscribe((name) => {
      console.log(name)
      this.user = name;
    });
  }

  logout(): void {
    this.userService.logout();
  }
}
```

and this is the result of the console.log, for some reason the name was an empty string for a second then it got changed very quickly to the wanted value

now when i want to display the dropdown and the sign in and login buttons based on the user value , the dropdown never shows  only after i reload

**this is the relative part of the html (im using the new angular v17 control flow)**

[image]

```
@if(!user){<a
          class="flex items-center gap-x-2 font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-blue-600 md:border-s md:border-gray-300 md:my-6 md:ps-6 dark:border-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:text-blue-500 cursor-pointer"
          routerLink="/register"
        >
          <i class="pi pi-user-plus"></i>
          Sign up
        </a>
        <a
          class="flex items-center gap-x-2 font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-blue-600 md:border-s md:border-gray-300 md:my-6 md:ps-6 dark:border-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:text-blue-500 cursor-pointer"
          routerLink="/login"
        >
          <i class="pi pi-user"></i>
          Log in </a
        >} @else if ( user ) {

        <div class="card flex justify-content-center hs-dropdown">
          <Button
            class="flex items-center gap-x-2 font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-blue-600 md:border-s md:border-gray-300 md:my-6 md:ps-6 dark:border-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:text-blue-500 cursor-pointer"
          >
            <i class="pi pi-user"></i>
            {{ user }}
          </Button>

          <div
            class="hs-dropdown-menu hidden transition-[opacity,margin] duration hs-dropdown-open:opacity-100 opacity-0 min-w-[15rem] bg-white shadow-md rounded-lg p-2 mt-2 divide-y divide-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border dark:border-gray-700 dark:divide-gray-700"
            aria-labelledby="hs-dropdown-with-dividers"
          >
            <div class="py-2 first:pt-0 last:pb-0">
              <a
                class="flex items-center gap-x-3.5 py-2 px-3 rounded-lg text-sm text-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-gray-300 dark:focus:bg-gray-700"
                href="#"
              >
                Upgrade License
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="py-2 first:pt-0 last:pb-0">
              <a
                class="flex items-center gap-x-3.5 py-2 px-3 rounded-lg text-sm text-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-gray-300 dark:focus:bg-gray-700"
                href="#"
              >
                Account Settings
              </a>
              <Button
                class="flex items-center gap-x-3.5 py-2 px-3 rounded-lg text-sm text-gray-100 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 dark:text-red-500 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-gray-300 dark:focus:bg-gray-700"
                (click)="logout()"
              >
                <i class="pi pi-sign-out"></i>
                Sign out
              </Button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        }
```

the value of {{ user}} shows fine but the dropdown doesnt show because its still stuck to the empty value of the this.user,
**Keep in mind everything works fine if i reload the page**

i tried to mess around with changing the **BehaviourSubject** to **EventEmitter** and still the same result at the end,

i think the problem is because the header is initialized before everything since it exists always in the app.component.html thats why its not reading the needed value, but the weird thing about it that the value of the user name shows

this is the result after realoding the page

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you're not calling UserService.logout() somewhere in your code?

Comment: yes im sure here is even my github repo for the project

Comment: https://github.com/Oussemasahbeni/restApiFront

Comment: Use debugger. Insert a conditional breakpoint (when name is empty) and see where it comes from.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and assign the user like `user = this.userService.currentUser;` and then use the async pipe in the template!

```
@if (user$ | async; as user) {
// your code goes here
}
```

Comment: still same thing nothing changed here is the output of the console.log

```22:40:20.010 | +37 sec   
  Observable2 {
    source: BehaviorSubject2 {
      closed: false,
      currentObservers: null,
      observers: [],
      isStopped: false,
      hasError: false,
      thrownError: null,
      _value: null
    }
  }
22:39:35.277 | +1 min   
  Observable2 {
    source: BehaviorSubject2 {
      closed: false,
      currentObservers: [],
      observers: [],
      isStopped: false,
      hasError: false,
      thrownError: null,
      _value: 'Oussema'
    }
  } ```

Answer (score 0):

on user `UserService`, i think u need to remove the code inside the constructor because it will trigger the behaviour subject again

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../../model/user';
import { BehaviorSubject, startWith, tap } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
  private url = "http://Localhost:8080/"
  private currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<string>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user') || 'null'));
  currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    // const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user') || 'null');
    // if (user) {
    //   this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
    // }
  }

  // ...
}
```

but regarding why does your observable return empty string, that im not sure